# Preventing Spammers from Creating Account in Media Wiki

Tags: php, mediawiki, captcha, wiki, spam

I have recently implemented the Media Wiki onto a subdomain of one of my websites. Excluding a few issues with IIS, it has gone pretty smoothly.

However, I am now receiving a lot of 'Message Delivery Failure' emails where accounts have been created but the email address has not been able to be verified, in other words, the email address does not exist (it is SPAM, I think).

My question, quite simply, is how do I implement some sort of security, either a CAPTCHA or something else, onto the 'Create Account' page?

I have read through the following two pages but it does not really make it clear how/if it is possible on this particular page. In addition, the instructions on the page really relate to Linux, and much to my disagreement, the server this site is sitting on is Windows and is running IIS.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Anti-spam_features

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Combating_spam

Any help much appreciated

**UPDATE**

I have also looked into implementing the 'Open ID' feature, but not quite sure how this works and whether it would sort this issue. Again, the instructions seem to only relate to Linux, if anybody can shed any light on how to achieve this with Windows and IIS please feel free to answer:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how much legitimate users you expect, maybe the ConfirmAccount extension can be usefull
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmAccount

Probably it not stop spammers from trying to subscribe, but at least the account are not created automatically.